# Nuget Update: File is already in use [concurrency file access]

Tags: c#, build, msbuild, dependencies, nuget

I have parallel builds that use same dependencies of nuget, and whenever I have 2 or more builds running update at the same time, one of that fails the update given the error the *xxx.dll file is being used by another process*. The folder is cache folder of nuget.

Do you have some solution to this kind of error?

This is related to concurrency file access

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround on this:

I have a common build, with trigger on each change in source control, that download the common folder to the machine, then, in each build, instead download the data from source control, I copy+paste the file from common path in machine to build folder.

Anyway, if you found anyway to do that, please share.